# Desktop load (Gnome or Netbook edition) jams after upgrading to 2.6.35 kernel

Tags: boot, kernel, ubuntu-netbook

After upgrading to 2.6.35 kernel, my netbook jams and I need to press the Enter key many times to resume the desktop load (Gnome or Netbook edition.

How to diagnose the problem and identify the root causes? How can I solve that problem?

Extra info: when I choose to boot with the previous kernels with Grub, I don't have this problem anymore.

Comment: Can you post the output of `dmesg` and possibly `lshw`? Also when you boot, can you edit the menu entry to remove the quiet part and see what output it is giving you that causes you to have to press enter? If you need more details on how to do that, leave a comment and I'll try to help.

Comment: I updated the question: It is the Desktop load that causes problem not the initial boot. Actually, after choosing the desktop (login screen), the desktop load stops until I press Enter key.

Answer (score 2):

Hold the right-shift key after the bios checks to bring up the grub menu. Then edit the menu line highlighted by hitting 'e'. Remove "quiet splash" from the line that starts "linux /boot/vmlinuz" by hitting "END" to get to the end and using "backspace". Do not remove any / on the line. Now use Ctrl+x to boot. You should be able to read the messages as they appear.